# How to redirect old rewrite rules 301 in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect old redirect rules permanently (301) created in htaccess to new rules as Google has fetched old urls which are resulting in 404 returns now. Please let me know how can I do this

This is my old Redirect rule:

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ page.php?value=$1 [L]

I'd like to redirect above rule permanently to :-

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-State$ page.php?value=$1 [L]

and would like redirect the following :-

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-Based-In-([^/]*)-District-([^/]*)$ page1.php?area=$1&district=$2&state=$3 [L]

to

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-Area-([^/]*)$ page1.php?area=$1&district=$2 [L]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for this if not please clarify

After **Edit**

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ $1-State/ [R]
RewriteRule  ^([^/])-Based-In-([^/])-District-([^/]*)$ $1-Area-$2 [R]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Abhishek but unfortunately this is not I'm asking for. Let me clarify here:
I want (1st rule for 1st level pages:)

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ page.php?value=$1 [L] (this was generating URLs like domain.com/pagename/
It should redirect 301 permanently to
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-State$ page.php?value=$1 [L] (it is generating URLs like domain.com/pagename-State

Like wise I want to add redirect rule to 2nd level and 3rd level pages as well.

Comment: you mean `domain.com/pagename/` will rewritten as `domain.com/pagename-state/` that's is you are asking

Comment: Yes @abhishek this is what I'm looking for. Both the forms of URLs based on htacess rule so I'd like to redirect Old rule to new one